# Can not use arguments in a stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in flutter , i have an api and i used Navigator to pass data to this Route , it works fine but only when i call the arguments in build method , outside of build method , they can not be recognized , my goal is to use my arguments outside of the build method to be able to create an api call that uses an id argument . the problem is in getClubs method and InitState method

here what i have tried

```
   import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'club_arguments.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


class ClubDetails extends StatefulWidget {

   final int id;
   final String name;
   final String image;
   final String rank;
   final String nationality;
   final String stadium;
   final  String manager;
   final String wins;
   final String draws;
   final String losses;
   final int goals;
   final int goalsIn;


   ClubDetails({ this.id, this.name,this.image,this.rank,this.nationality,this.stadium,this.manager,this.wins,this.draws,this.losses,this.goals,this.goalsIn});

  @override
  _ClubDetailsState createState() => _ClubDetailsState();
}

class _ClubDetailsState extends State<ClubDetails> {

  String stadium;
  String founded;


  getClub(int id) async {

    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'http://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/$id',
        headers: {'X-Auth-Token': '86014f6025ae430dba078acc94bb2647'});
    String body = response.body;
    Map data = jsonDecode(body);
    stadium = data['name'];

    //Club(this.id,this.name,this.image,this.rank,this.nationality,this.stadium,this.manager,this.wins,this.draws,this.losses,this.goals,this.goalsIn);
    setState(() {
      //print(data[0]['venue']);
      print(stadium);
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getClub(widget.id);
    print(widget.id);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Titles> titles = [
      Titles("LA LIGA", "Spain","Barcelona","2008" ),
    ];


    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Club Info"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                  colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue])
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.black38])),
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child:    Card(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child:
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            child:
                            SvgPicture.network(widget.image,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width:10.0),
                          Spacer(),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: <Widget> [
                              Text(widget.name, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                              Text("rank : "+widget.rank, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                              Text("Found : "+widget.manager, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                              Text("Nationality : "+widget.nationality, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                              Text("Stadium : "+widget.stadium, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 10),
                  child:  Text(
                    "Achieved Titles",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return Card(
                        elevation: 4.0,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child:
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://www.impacttrophies.co.uk/content/images/thumbs/0065685_tower-football-trophy-gold.jpeg"),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width:10.0),
                              Spacer(),
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: <Widget> [
                                  Text(titles[index].name, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                  )),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                                  Text("country : "+titles[index].country, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                                  )),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                                  Text("club : "+titles[index].club, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                                  )),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                                  Text("year : "+titles[index].year, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                                  )),
                                ],
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: titles.length,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 70,
                ),
              ],
            ),

          )
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Stats{

  String title;
  String result;

  Stats(this.title,this.result);

}

class Team {

  String name;
  String image;
  String date;

  Team(this.name,this.image,this.date);

}


class Titles {
  String name;
  String country;
  String club;
  String year;

  Titles(this.name,this.country,this.club,this.year);

}

class Club {

  int id;
  String name;
  String image;
  String rank;
  String nationality;
  String stadium;
  String manager;
  String wins;
  String draws;
  String losses;
  int goals;
  int goalsIn;


  Club(this.id, this.name, this.image, this.rank, this.nationality,
      this.stadium, this.manager, this.wins, this.draws, this.losses,
      this.goals, this.goalsIn);

}
```

My goal is to call my method getClub using my argument id as a parameter , and to use my id argument that i received from previous route in my request url

Comment: Please share the error you are receiving.

Comment: the error is i find in console that my json value are null , except the id value , all the values from backend are null when i use print in initState

Comment: i found this error when i use my query result : ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following ArgumentError was thrown building ClubDetails(dirty, state: _ClubDetailsState#fc3e7):
Invalid argument(s)

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ClubDetails file:///C:/Users/Fares/AndroidStudioProjects/tl_fantasy/lib/clubs/club_navigation_bar.dart:33:42
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _StringBase.+ (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:267:57)
....

Comment: I would say that is a problem with your backend. Test it with something else like Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the parameter to your widget class, and then use that inside your state class like this:

```
    class ClubDetails extends StatefulWidget {
       final int id ;

       ClubDetails({this.id});

      @override
      _ClubDetailsState createState() => _ClubDetailsState();
    }
```

and then you can use it in your state class (`_ClubDetailsState`) using the `widget` like this.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getClub(widget.id);
  }
```

you don't need to create `id` variable inside your state class (`_ClubDetailsState`) anymore

now, you can easily pass the id value as a argument to your widget while constructing it, like this:

```
ClubDetails(id : 1);
```

Comment: i passed already an object to my class , look on build methods and you will find arguments variables , it is all what i passed

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is declare the variables in the `Stateful Widget` and set them in the constructor. Then on the `State Widget`, you access them with the `widget.` prefix, like this:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Issue66934490(name: 'name');
  }
}

class Issue66934490 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  
  Issue66934490({
    this.name,
  });
  
  @override
  _Issue66934490State createState() => _Issue66934490State();
}

class _Issue66934490State extends State<Issue66934490> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.name),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i still have a problem @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getClub(widget.id);
    print(widget.id);
  } here widget.id is null , can you tell me why ? i will update my code

Comment: You aren't showing us where you are calling the `ClubDetails` widget class. Are you sure you aren't passing a `null` id?

Comment: ok now i added the id to the ClubDetails Widget , it is not null , but my problem is that the json values that i want to get , when i try to print them in initState method , i find them null